# Consider defining a bean of type in your configuration issue

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to access `@Mapper` annotated interface in my `@Service` class

here is my Service class

```
@Service
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {

    private PostRepository postRepository;
    private PostMapper postMapper;

    public PostServiceImpl(PostRepository postRepository, PostMapper postMapper) {

        this.postRepository = postRepository;
        this.postMapper = postMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public PostDto createPost(PostDto postDto) {

        Post npo = postMapper.getPost(postDto);
        postRepository.save(npo);
        PostDto retrunStatus = postMapper.getPostDto(npo);

        return retrunStatus;

    }

    @Override
    public List<PostDto> getAllPosts() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

and here is my Mapper class

```
@Mapper( imports = {Instant.class, DateTimeFormatter.class})
@Configuration
public interface PostMapper {
    
    Post getPost(PostDto postDto);
    
    PostDto getPostDto(Post post);

}
```

but am getting below error, while starting spring boot application

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.rest.api.service.impl.PostServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.rest.api.mapper.PostMapper' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.rest.api.mapper.PostMapper' in your configuration.
```

It was running fine when I was not using mapper but using manually mapping `PostDto to Post`

Can anyone suggest what am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

`PostMapper`'s `interface` doesn't have any `bean` in which implements it.
For example:

```
@Component
public class PostMapperImpl implements PostMapper{
  // override the PostMapper methods
}
```

BTW, the error that Spring throws tell you that.

Comment: But do I need to write this PostMapper implementation explicitly  ? Dont sprint do that at runtime to map these objects ?

Comment: Map what to what? Spring doesn't create an implementations to you.

Comment: PostDto to Post object

Comment: Does PostMapper has any default implementation (and it is Spring Bean?) that Spring has a way to know it?

Comment: PostMapper has no default implementation...what can be done if I simply wants to map these to objects vice versa ?

Comment: I suggest to map with Orika ("Java Bean mapping framework that recursively copies data from one object to another.") I use it. BTW, does my answer helped with your problem?

Comment: please check this link https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct   it says Spring automatically implements it and copy thing happens